# Is there a way to iterate a flux, find if its elements exist or else save them on db?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm having troubles while mapping a flux of elements. what I'm trying to achieve is to check if the elements are already saved in the database or else save them. This would work if the elements were already present on the database, but if there are new entries and some of them are duplicated (and I cannot remove duplicates because I'll need them later), there's no way that the find operation would work.

For example, given a flux which emits ["service", "service", "products"] and an empty database, what would happen is that my code will save all, while I'd expect to save only ["service","products"]. This happens since reactor won't eagerly save until the flux's flatmap is completed.

Is there a way to make sure that a nested save operation would complete before the flux emits the next element?

```
        Flux<CsvBean> csvBeanFlux = byteArrayInputStreamMono.flatMapIterable(this::parseCsv);

    return csvBeanFlux.flatMap(csvBean -> {
        DictionaryFilter level1Filter = generateDictionaryFilter(dictionary, csvBean.getLevel1(), locale);
        return dictionaryService
                .findOne(level1Filter).log("FIND LEVEL1")
                .switchIfEmpty(mongoTemplate.save(generateCodeValue(locale, csvBean.getLevel1(), UUID.randomUUID().toString(), null), dictionary).log("SAVE LEVEL1"));
    });
```

Comment: You can try concatMap instead of flatMap. It will process items sequentially.

Comment: It worked! you saved me after I spent a week looking in the reference docs and only managed to find flatMapSequence which didn't work. Thank you!